# is 'nodetool repair -pr -par' a full repair?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

We do run repair -pr on every DSC 2.1.15 node within gc_grace like this:

```
nodetool -h localhost repair -pr -par mykeyspc
```

But in the log it says `full=true`:

```
[2017-02-12 00:00:01,683] Starting repair command #11, repairing 256 ranges for
     keyspace mykeyspc (parallelism=PARALLEL, full=true)
```

Would have expected that a -pr didn't run a full repair or how to read this log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means full as in "not incremental". Can think of it as its *fully* repairing the data in those ranges, not just the unrepaired data. It is confusing argument naming. The `-pr` means its just repairing the primary ranges though so you still need to do that on each node.